# How to set keepalive option for induvidual socket in VxWorks

Tags: vxworks, sockets

Is there any way to set keepalive for induvidual socket descriptor in vxworks? I read in some documents that "SOL_TCP" option in setsockopt function will do such favors in linux. Is such facility available in VxWorks too? If so please provide related details regarding the same, like what are the include file we need to include and how to use such option etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the VxWorks "Library Reference" manual (can be download):

**OPTIONS FOR STREAM SOCKETS**

The following sections discuss the socket options available for stream (TCP) sockets.

**SO_KEEPALIVE** -- Detecting a Dead Connection

Specify the SO_KEEPALIVE option to make the transport protocol (TCP) initiate a timer to detect a dead connection:

```
 setsockopt (sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, sizeof (optval));
```

This prevents an application from hanging on an invalid connection. The value at optval for this option is an integer (type int), either 1 (on) or 0 (off).
The integrity of a connection is verified by transmitting zero-length TCP segments triggered by a timer, to force a response from a peer node. If the peer does not respond after repeated transmissions of the **KEEPALIVE** segments, the connection is dropped, all protocol data structures are reclaimed, and processes sleeping on the connection are awakened with an **ETIMEDOUT** error.

The **ETIMEDOUT** timeout can happen in two ways. If the connection is not yet established, the **KEEPALIVE** timer expires after idling for **TCPTV_KEEP_INIT**. If the connection is established, the KEEPALIVE timer starts up when there is no traffic for **TCPTV_KEEP_IDLE**. If no response is received from the peer after sending the **KEEPALIVE** segment **TCPTV_KEEPCNT** times with interval **TCPTV_KEEPINTVL**, TCP assumes that the connection is invalid. The parameters **TCPTV_KEEP_INIT**, **TCPTV_KEEP_IDLE**, **TCPTV_KEEPCNT**, and **TCPTV_KEEPINTVL** are defined in the file target/h/net/tcp_timer.h.

Comment: Is it possible to set the timer value (KEEP ALIVE TIMER) for individual socket? Kind share the vxWorks "Library Reference" manual link.

Answer (score 0):

IP_TCP_KEEPINTVL and also TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPCNT options supported by setsockopt after vxworks 6.8 version. In former releases of vxworks you can change these values globally and all the sockets created effected. 
Below question is an answer for how will it be done.

[How to set TCP keep alive interval for a specific socket fd (Not system wide) in VxWorks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57326996/how-to-set-tcp-keep-alive-interval-for-a-specific-socket-fd-not-system-wide-in)